# iAd covers my UIButton Spritekit

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, iad

While running iOS 8.3 and using SpriteKit, setting the `canDisplayAds` property to `true` in my `ViewController` causes the bottom of my devices screen to have an `ADBannerView` overlapping my `UIButton`. When a user touches the screen for the first time the `ADBannerView` moves up and the `UIButton` is no longer covered. Has anyone experienced this before? Are there any easy workarounds?

Comment: Try calling `layoutIfNeeded` on your view.